# ajax response while VPN disconnected

Tags: jquery

I am using VPN to connect to my server and sending jquery ajax requests.While VPN connections lost, How the ajax behaves?

Comment: I think just trying it would be a lot faster than to wait for an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same behavior as other HTTP requests: the request ends with Not-Found [HTTP 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) error code! The XMLHttpRequest's [onreadystate](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) event also fires with the Not-Found status code.